# Notification for chat application in android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

how would i get a notification in android  chat application....
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

```
        nBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_indietext);
        nBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification from IndeText");

        Intent nIntent=new Intent(this,ConvActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder nStackBuilder=TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        nStackBuilder.addParentStack(ConvActivity.class);

        nStackBuilder.addNextIntent(nIntent);
        PendingIntent nPendingInten=nStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        nBuilder.setContentIntent(nPendingInten);

        NotificationManager nNotificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nNotificationManager.notify(99999,nBuilder.build());
```

I am using this code in my main activity..and  when  we click on the notification i  want to open the same activity

Comment: Do you want to open your MainActivity after clicking the notification?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setData(myUri);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(notificationData.Title)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_notification))
            .setContentText(notificationData.Description)
            .setStyle(notiStyle).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
 PendingIntent nPendingInten=nStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

with

```
PendingIntent nPendingInten= PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, nIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```